# django tables 2 - add custom column

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm using django-tables-2 for a project. I have a table that uses a model for displaying data but I need to add one more column to display some informations from another table. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```py
# models.py
class Person(models.Model):
    " This is your regular model "
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User")
    dob = models.DateField()

class PersonTable(tables.Table):
   id = tables.Column(name="id") # just add a field here
   class Meta:
       model = Person
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't works. The column appears but there is nothing in the cells, even if in render_<column_name> method I return informations.

Comment: How are your models set up? You could use the `accessor` attribute on the column. Have a look at the [example](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#customising-column-headings)

Answer (score 0):

You map the column either by having the same name of the model's attribute, either using the accessor property.

I guess in your case it would be:

```
class UsersTable(tables.Table):

    custom = Column(_("Custom"), accessor='id', orderable=False) # Any attr will do, dont mind it

    def render_custom(self, record):
        return services.get_some_info(record)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (b'username', )
```